# Can I get Eliza to forget I am working on a request?

Tags: rune-factory-4

I have a request right now that I don't think I can complete. Is there any way to get Eliza to forget about it so I can go and accomplish other things?

Answer (score 1):

In your journal, you can see what requests you currently have. When looking at the details of the request, you should have an option to delete/abandon the request.